# Android opening new page after onActivityResult

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-camera

For a HTML5 - Jquery Mobile Android app I use native code to access the camera. I have succeeded in getting images from the camera and showing them on my local webpage. The problem I'm experiencing is that when the camera intent closes my web page seems to reopen itself a second time only this time javascript isn't executed. When I press the back button on my device I get redirected to the right page again.

How can I keep my page from opening twice?

I'm using following code to access my camera:

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        public void performClick() {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd_HH.mm.ss")
                    .format(new Date());
            IMG = new File(APP_LOCATION + File.separator + "images",
                    timeStamp + ".jpg");
            IMG_LOCATION = Uri.fromFile(IMG);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, IMG_LOCATION);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        }
    }, "openCamera");


@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                storeImage(data.getData(), IMG);
            } else {
                storeImage(IMG_LOCATION, IMG);
            }
            // Call JavaScript function to display image on the webpage
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setImage(\"" + IMG_LOCATION
                    + "\")");
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your activity tag in manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it doesn't like calling javascript from onActivityResult. Use the following instead of the simple loadUrl call:

```
// Call JavaScript function to display image on the webpage
RunOnUiThread(new Java.Lang.Runnable(() =>
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setImage(\"" + IMG_LOCATION
            + "\")"); 
    }
});
```